# Adding pagination in cakephp with multiple join tables and conditions

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pagination

here $qoptions contains the conditions according to which data is fetched from different tables and $tmp is basically the query which is getting diff fields value from different tables. Now where should I add pagination .. If i add acccording to user table result than am not getting correct pagination result according to my data.

```
            $tmp=$this->User->find('all', 
         array(
           'fields' => array('User.id', 'User.name','user_details.designation','districts.district_name','User.user_type','User.phone','user_details.annual_frequency','areas.area_name') ,
           'joins' => array(array('table' => 'user_details',
                                   'alias' => 'user_details',
                                   'type' => 'INNER',
                                   'conditions' => array('User.id = user_details.user_id AND user_details.annual_frequency>0')
                             ),
                   array('table' => 'areas',
                                   'alias' => 'areas',
                                   'type' => 'INNER',
                                   'conditions' => array('User.area_id = areas.id')
                             ),
                  array('table' => 'districts',
                                   'alias' => 'districts',
                                   'type' => 'INNER',
                                   'conditions' => array('areas.district_id = districts.id')
                             )

        ),
                'conditions' => $qOptions,  

             )
      );         $this->paginate = ($tmp)
             $p = $this->paginate('User');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out the book, http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html, this should help you along.